# Maven command line

Tags: java, maven-2, command-line, debugging

Is it possible to set environmental variables in a build profile as opposed to setting them in the command line?

For instance, I want to enable the debugger when I'm using my test environment (-Denv=test).

I want maven to do this:

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

This way, I can quickly attach a debugger without having to type the same repeated line over and over.

I don't believe the  helps me in this case:

```
<plugin>
...
<!--    Automatically enable the debugger when running Jetty    -->
                    <argLine>-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n</argLine>
                </configuration>
...
</plugin>
```

Walter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In recent versions of Maven you can activate the debugger by running **mvnDebug** rather than **mvn**, the mvnDebug bat/sh file sets MVN__DEBUG_OPTS and passes them to the java.exe. The values passed are:

```
set MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000
```

If that isn't sufficient, this may work (note I've not yet tested this, I'll update once I have). Maven reads properties prefixed with "env." from the environment, you may be able to set environment variables by prefixing with the same. i.e.:

```
<profile>
  <id>dev</id>
  <properties>
    <env.MAVEN_OPTS>-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000<env.MAVEN_OPTS>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

Update: The surefire plugin allows you to [specify system properties](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) to be used during test execution. The configuration is as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <systemProperties>
      <property>
        <name>propertyName</name>
        <value>propertyValue</value>
      </property>
    </systemProperties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If none of those work for you, it is possible to write a small plugin configured in your profile that binds to the initialize phase and sets your variables. The plugin would have configuration like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>name.seller.rich</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-environment-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>set-properties</id>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>set-properties</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>                              
  <configuration>
    <properties>
      <env.MAVEN_OPTS>-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE 
          -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8000<env.MAVEN_OPTS>
    </properties>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

during execution the plugin would set each passed property using System.setProperty(). If the first two aren't suitable or don't work this should address your issue.

Comment: Hi Rich,

The mvnDebug command worked, but it appears to hang quite a bit and eat a lot of memory.  I haven't had any luck with those other options yet, but I will keep trying.


Walter